# Appium - Unable to take the locators from Appium for Apple Sign-In popup in 16.x OS version

Tags: ios, selenium-webdriver, testing, appium, appium-ios

In a native iOS Mobile app, we need to login the app through Apple sign-in using Mobile Automation.

From Appium, while trying to take the locator of the Apple sign-in popup, we are unable to take locator in the 16.x OS version.
Device Model: iPhone 11
OS version: 16.6.1
Button to be accessed: "Continue with Password"

Is there any alternate way to access this Apple sign-in popup from Appium?

We tried in other OS versions like 15.x and 17.x, where we could access that popup and take the locators successfully. It is not working only in 16.6.1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLAK4.png)